# Reverse an array and finding the valid value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an reversed array

```
 NSArray *reversedArray = [[arr reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

It contains following value

Reversed Array: (
    0,
    0,
    "0.1702998",
    "0.4936719",
    0,
    "0.1861508",
)

So the value which are comming are dynamic, So i want the first non zero value from this array.

How can i do this?

Comment: Do both `0` and `"0.0000000"` count as zero?

Comment: Yes i do not need both of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double firstNonZeroValue = 0.0;
for (NSString* stringValue in [array reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    double value = [stringValue doubleValue];
    if (value != 0.0) {
        firstNonZeroValue = value;
        break;
    }
}

if (firstNonZeroValue != 0.0) {
    ... yay found a non zero value ...
}
```